# How I make rss feed like blogger

Tags: php, xml, rss

guys I am doing some stuff which is related to rssfeed. I built a page for rss feed all the things are going well but when I try to test the feed or use the feed I can't, Here is my code. Actually I am building rss feed for my blogger so I want to be it like that, any ways just tell me where am I wrong

```
        <?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$xml=simplexml_load_file("ad.xml");
header('Content-Type: application/atom+xml');
$b="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed>";
    echo $b;
foreach($xml->url as $s){
    $s=$s->loc;
$html = file_get_html($s);
 $element= $html->find('div[class=post-content clear-block]');
// Find all links 
$vez=$html->find('div[class=post-date]');
$p = '|<a [^>]*href="http://onlinegamesocean.com[^"]*"[^>]*>.*</a>|iU';
$h = $html->find('h1[class=title]');

if(empty($vez)){
    foreach($h as $ha){
echo "<entry><title type='text'>".htmlentities($ha->plaintext)."</title>";
}
foreach($element as $a) {
    if ($a === end($element))
echo "<content type='html'>".htmlentities(preg_replace($p, '', $a))."</content></entry>";
}
}
}
echo "</feed>";
?>
```

Output:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed><entry><title type='text'>Offworld Trading Company Free Download</title><content type='html'>&lt;div class=&quot;post-content clear-block&quot;&gt;                             &lt;p style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;h5&gt;ABOUT THE GAME&lt;/h5&gt; &lt;p&gt;Mars has been colonized and has invited you to lend a hand to make sure the new colony has a shot at success. But you&rsquo;re not the only one that&rsquo;s been invited, other business rivals are here as well and they have no qualms about playing dirty to gain the choicest territories on the Martian surface and driving their competitors out of business.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Title: Offworld Trading Company&lt;br /&gt; Genre: Indie, Simulation, Strategy&lt;br /&gt; Developer: Mohawk Games&lt;br /&gt; Publisher: Stardock Entertainment&lt;br /&gt; Release Date: 28 Apr, 2016&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;lazy lazy-hidden&quot; src=&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=&quot; data-cke-saved-src=&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=&quot; data-lazy-type=&quot;image&quot; data-lazy-src=&quot;http://i57.tinypic.com/5oi24i.jpg&quot; /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company.DLC-BAT &lt;/strong&gt;{ &lt;a href=&quot;http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/5n5nCVek/file.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/5n5nCVek/file.html&quot;&gt;Download &lt;/a&gt;| &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.sendspace.com/file/5jvzun&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://www.sendspace.com/file/5jvzun&quot;&gt;Download &lt;/a&gt;| &lt;a href=&quot;https://openload.co/f/tiwRzi0Uf9c/b-oftrcodlc.rar&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://openload.co/f/tiwRzi0Uf9c/b-oftrcodlc.rar&quot;&gt;Download &lt;/a&gt;| &lt;a href=&quot;http://hugefiles.net/4ku46juf0xty&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://hugefiles.net/4ku46juf0xty&quot;&gt;Download &lt;/a&gt;| &lt;a href=&quot;https://1fichier.com/?duu3oi6j1g&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://1fichier.com/?duu3oi6j1g&quot;&gt;Download &lt;/a&gt;| &lt;a href=&quot;https://userscloud.com/9aowye1vsf04&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://userscloud.com/9aowye1vsf04&quot;&gt;Download &lt;/a&gt;| &lt;a href=&quot;http://up07.net/4yz42d55gvi4&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://up07.net/4yz42d55gvi4&quot;&gt;Download &lt;/a&gt;| &lt;a href=&quot;http://jheberg.net/captcha/b-oftrcodlc/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://jheberg.net/captcha/b-oftrcodlc/&quot;&gt;Download &lt;/a&gt;| &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.multiup.org/download/329c0ab802c97f5a48a728ea27000235/b-oftrcodlc.rar&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://www.multiup.org/download/329c0ab802c97f5a48a728ea27000235/b-oftrcodlc.rar&quot;&gt;Download &lt;/a&gt;}&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;DLC&rsquo;s:&lt;br /&gt; &bull; Offworld Trading Company &ndash; Real Mars Map Pack DLC&lt;br /&gt; &bull; Offworld Trading Company &ndash; Almanac DLC&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Note:&lt;br /&gt; &bull; Game prompts an early access notice on first run, but it is out of EA state as also evident on the version number v1.0.12745&lt;br /&gt; &bull; Also the DLC&rsquo;s only became available after EA state changed&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Offworld Trading Company Free Download&lt;br /&gt; Size: 656 MB&lt;br /&gt; &mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;-&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;ONE FTP LINK&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DIRECT LINK&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://kumpulbagi.id/anas45/anas45-363423/hi-oftrco,2697520.iso&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://kumpulbagi.id/anas45/anas45-363423/hi-oftrco,2697520.iso&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;OPENLOAD&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://openload.co/f/1b-KUEcxT8g/hi-oftrco.iso&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://openload.co/f/1b-KUEcxT8g/hi-oftrco.iso&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;UP07&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://up07.net/uyr0e7zq4mxt&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://up07.net/uyr0e7zq4mxt&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;1FICHIER&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://1fichier.com/?c8p9sz5gci&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://1fichier.com/?c8p9sz5gci&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;UPTOBOX&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://uptobox.com/5ovs6xtrdamz&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://uptobox.com/5ovs6xtrdamz&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;HUGEFILES&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;!-- Quick Adsense WordPress Plugin: http://quicksense.net/ --&gt; &lt;div style=&quot;float:none;margin:10px 0 10px 0;text-align:center;&quot;&gt; &lt;center&gt;&lt;script language='Javascript'&gt;  &lt;!--  document.write(unescape('%3C%64%69%76%20%73%74%79%6C%65%3D%22%68%65%69%67%68%74%3A%32%38%32%70%78%3B%77%69%64%74%68%3A%33%33%36%70%78%3B%6F%76%65%72%66%6C%6F%77%3A%68%69%64%64%65%6E%3B%62%61%63%6B%67%72%6F%75%6E%64%3A%23%63%63%63%3B%22%20%69%64%3D%22%61%64%64%69%76%22%3E%0A%3C%69%66%72%61%6D%65%20%73%74%79%6C%65%3D%22%68%65%69%67%68%74%3A%37%35%30%70%78%3B%77%69%64%74%68%3A%33%33%36%70%78%22%20%73%72%63%3D%22%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%6F%63%63%65%61%6E%67%61%6D%65%73%72%65%76%69%65%77%73%2E%62%6C%6F%67%73%70%6F%74%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%70%2F%32%35%30%2E%68%74%6D%6C%3F%69%64%3D%78%32%6B%67%30%33%6A%22%20%73%63%72%6F%6C%6C%69%6E%67%3D%22%6E%6F%22%20%69%64%3D%22%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%22%3E%3C%2F%69%66%72%61%6D%65%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%3C%21%2D%2D%61%64%64%20%6A%71%75%65%72%79%20%69%66%20%6E%6F%74%20%61%64%64%65%64%2D%2D%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%61%6A%61%78%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%61%70%69%73%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%61%6A%61%78%2F%6C%69%62%73%2F%6A%71%75%65%72%79%2F%31%2E%31%31%2E%33%2F%6A%71%75%65%72%79%2E%6D%69%6E%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%3C%21%2D%2D%61%64%64%20%6A%71%75%65%72%79%20%69%66%20%6E%6F%74%20%61%64%64%65%64%2F%2D%2D%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%6A%51%75%65%72%79%28%77%69%6E%64%6F%77%29%2E%6C%6F%61%64%28%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%20%7B%0A%6A%51%75%65%72%79%28%22%23%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%22%29%2E%6C%6F%61%64%28%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%20%7B%6A%51%75%65%72%79%28%27%23%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%27%29%2E%63%73%73%28%27%68%65%69%67%68%74%27%2C%27%39%30%27%29%0A%73%65%74%54%69%6D%65%6F%75%74%28%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%7B%20%6A%51%75%65%72%79%28%27%23%61%64%64%69%76%27%29%2E%63%73%73%28%27%62%61%63%6B%67%72%6F%75%6E%64%27%2C%27%74%72%61%6E%73%70%61%72%65%6E%74%27%29%7D%2C%20%31%30%30%30%20%29%3B%7D%29%3B%0A%24%28%27%23%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%27%29%2E%6C%6F%61%64%28%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%20%7B%24%28%27%23%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%27%29%2E%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%73%28%29%2E%66%69%6E%64%28%22%62%6F%64%79%22%29%2E%61%64%64%43%6C%61%73%73%28%27%69%66%72%61%6D%65%64%27%29%3B%7D%29%3B%0A%7D%29%3B%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E'));  //--&gt;  &lt;/script&gt;&lt;/center&gt; &lt;/div&gt;  &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://hugefiles.net/q0iqt3v4cy21&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://hugefiles.net/q0iqt3v4cy21&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;MEDIAFREE&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://mediafree.co/l2y54l6fqew1/hi-oftrco.iso.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://mediafree.co/l2y54l6fqew1/hi-oftrco.iso.html&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;USERSCLOUD&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://userscloud.com/krigot141ekc&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://userscloud.com/krigot141ekc&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;JHEBERG&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://jheberg.net/captcha/hi-oftrco/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://jheberg.net/captcha/hi-oftrco/&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;GO4UP&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://go4up.com/dl/9bffa4cfb5f8/hi-oftrco.iso&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://go4up.com/dl/9bffa4cfb5f8/hi-oftrco.iso&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;MULTI LINKS&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.multiup.org/download/8a76e30e7547e475ff0709052b81235a/hi-oftrco.iso&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://www.multiup.org/download/8a76e30e7547e475ff0709052b81235a/hi-oftrco.iso&quot;&gt;Offworld.Trading.Company-HI2U.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;TORRENT&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;blockquote&gt;&lt;p&gt;Enjoy&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div id=&quot;tabs-21031-0-1&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;MINIMUM:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;ul&gt; &lt;li&gt; &lt;ul class=&quot;bb_ul&quot;&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;OS:&lt;/strong&gt; Windows 10 / 8.1 / 7 64-bit&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Processor:&lt;/strong&gt; 1.8 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo / 2.0 GHz AMD Athlon X2 64&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Memory:&lt;/strong&gt; 2 GB RAM&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Graphics:&lt;/strong&gt; Nvidia GeForce 8800 GT / ATI Radeon HD 3870 / Intel HD Graphics 4600&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DirectX:&lt;/strong&gt; Version 11&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Network:&lt;/strong&gt; Broadband Internet connection&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Storage:&lt;/strong&gt; 2 GB available space&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Sound Card:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_rightCol&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;RECOMMENDED:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;ul&gt; &lt;li&gt; &lt;ul class=&quot;bb_ul&quot;&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Processor:&lt;/strong&gt; 3 GHz Intel Quad-Core Processor / 3.2 GHz AMD Six-Core Processor&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Memory:&lt;/strong&gt; 4 GB RAM&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Graphics:&lt;/strong&gt; Nvidia GeForce GTX 460 / AMD Radeon HD 7850&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DirectX:&lt;/strong&gt; Version 11&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Network:&lt;/strong&gt; Broadband Internet connection&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Storage:&lt;/strong&gt; 2 GB available space&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Sound Card:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div id=&quot;tabs-21031-0-3&quot;&gt;&lt;center&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;iframe src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/wHWb_IsM1HU&quot; width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen=&quot;allowfullscreen&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/center&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;div id=&quot;tabs-21031-0-4&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Offworld Trading Company Free Download&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &amp;#8211; Extract&lt;br /&gt; &amp;#8211; Burn or mount the .iso&lt;br /&gt; &amp;#8211; Run setup.exe and install&lt;br /&gt; &amp;#8211; Copy Crack&lt;br /&gt; &amp;#8211; Play&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt;  &lt;div style=&quot;font-size:0px;height:0px;line-height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;clear:both&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;wp_rp_wrap  wp_rp_vertical_m&quot; id=&quot;wp_rp_first&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;wp_rp_content&quot;&gt;&lt;h3 class=&quot;related_post_title&quot;&gt;You May Also Like:&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;ul class=&quot;related_post wp_rp&quot;&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;0&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-22373&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;1&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-22225&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;2&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-23294&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;3&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-21988&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;4&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-22659&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;5&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-22357&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;                                                         &lt;/div&gt;</content></entry><entry><title type='text'>Left Alone Free Download</title><content type='html'>&lt;div class=&quot;post-content clear-block&quot;&gt;                             &lt;p style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;h5&gt;ABOUT THE GAME&lt;/h5&gt; &lt;p&gt;Left alone is a psychological horror game set in multiple believable interior and exterior environments. The game has a unique, high octane atmosphere which means you&rsquo;ll feel like you&rsquo;re truly beginning an adventure you&rsquo;ll never quite forget.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Title: Left Alone&lt;br /&gt; Genre: Action, Adventure, Indie&lt;br /&gt; Developer: Volumetric Games&lt;br /&gt; Publisher: Volumetric Games&lt;br /&gt; Release Date: 28 Apr, 2016&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Left Alone Free Download&lt;br /&gt; Size: 680 MB&lt;br /&gt; &mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;-&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;ONE FTP LINK&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DIRECT LINK&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://kumpulbagi.id/anas45/anas45-363423/plaza-left-alone,2696467.iso&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://kumpulbagi.id/anas45/anas45-363423/plaza-left-alone,2696467.iso&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;OPENLOAD&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://openload.co/f/ZYE1o2I-3Vc/plaza-left.alone.iso&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://openload.co/f/ZYE1o2I-3Vc/plaza-left.alone.iso&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;UP07&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://up07.net/5xicihuwfppk&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://up07.net/5xicihuwfppk&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;1FICHIER&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://1fichier.com/?9sy0zkmtaf&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://1fichier.com/?9sy0zkmtaf&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;UPTOBOX&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://uptobox.com/cn3svruftm6y&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://uptobox.com/cn3svruftm6y&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DOWNACE&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://downace.com/1jjM&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://downace.com/1jjM&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;HUGEFILES&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;!-- Quick Adsense WordPress Plugin: http://quicksense.net/ --&gt; &lt;div style=&quot;float:none;margin:10px 0 10px 0;text-align:center;&quot;&gt; &lt;center&gt;&lt;script language='Javascript'&gt;  &lt;!--  document.write(unescape('%3C%64%69%76%20%73%74%79%6C%65%3D%22%68%65%69%67%68%74%3A%32%38%32%70%78%3B%77%69%64%74%68%3A%33%33%36%70%78%3B%6F%76%65%72%66%6C%6F%77%3A%68%69%64%64%65%6E%3B%62%61%63%6B%67%72%6F%75%6E%64%3A%23%63%63%63%3B%22%20%69%64%3D%22%61%64%64%69%76%22%3E%0A%3C%69%66%72%61%6D%65%20%73%74%79%6C%65%3D%22%68%65%69%67%68%74%3A%37%35%30%70%78%3B%77%69%64%74%68%3A%33%33%36%70%78%22%20%73%72%63%3D%22%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%6F%63%63%65%61%6E%67%61%6D%65%73%72%65%76%69%65%77%73%2E%62%6C%6F%67%73%70%6F%74%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%70%2F%32%35%30%2E%68%74%6D%6C%3F%69%64%3D%78%32%6B%67%30%33%6A%22%20%73%63%72%6F%6C%6C%69%6E%67%3D%22%6E%6F%22%20%69%64%3D%22%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%22%3E%3C%2F%69%66%72%61%6D%65%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%3C%21%2D%2D%61%64%64%20%6A%71%75%65%72%79%20%69%66%20%6E%6F%74%20%61%64%64%65%64%2D%2D%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%61%6A%61%78%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%61%70%69%73%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%61%6A%61%78%2F%6C%69%62%73%2F%6A%71%75%65%72%79%2F%31%2E%31%31%2E%33%2F%6A%71%75%65%72%79%2E%6D%69%6E%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%3C%21%2D%2D%61%64%64%20%6A%71%75%65%72%79%20%69%66%20%6E%6F%74%20%61%64%64%65%64%2F%2D%2D%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%6A%51%75%65%72%79%28%77%69%6E%64%6F%77%29%2E%6C%6F%61%64%28%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%20%7B%0A%6A%51%75%65%72%79%28%22%23%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%22%29%2E%6C%6F%61%64%28%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%20%7B%6A%51%75%65%72%79%28%27%23%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%27%29%2E%63%73%73%28%27%68%65%69%67%68%74%27%2C%27%39%30%27%29%0A%73%65%74%54%69%6D%65%6F%75%74%28%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%7B%20%6A%51%75%65%72%79%28%27%23%61%64%64%69%76%27%29%2E%63%73%73%28%27%62%61%63%6B%67%72%6F%75%6E%64%27%2C%27%74%72%61%6E%73%70%61%72%65%6E%74%27%29%7D%2C%20%31%30%30%30%20%29%3B%7D%29%3B%0A%24%28%27%23%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%27%29%2E%6C%6F%61%64%28%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%29%20%7B%24%28%27%23%61%64%66%72%61%6D%65%27%29%2E%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%73%28%29%2E%66%69%6E%64%28%22%62%6F%64%79%22%29%2E%61%64%64%43%6C%61%73%73%28%27%69%66%72%61%6D%65%64%27%29%3B%7D%29%3B%0A%7D%29%3B%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E'));  //--&gt;  &lt;/script&gt;&lt;/center&gt; &lt;/div&gt;  &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://hugefiles.net/eotqcncouwxj&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://hugefiles.net/eotqcncouwxj&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;MEDIAFREE&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://mediafree.co/7fwl6l1mrhpy/plaza-left.alone.iso.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://mediafree.co/7fwl6l1mrhpy/plaza-left.alone.iso.html&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;USERSCLOUD&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://userscloud.com/gk64s7p2nxu9&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;https://userscloud.com/gk64s7p2nxu9&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;JHEBERG&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://jheberg.net/captcha/plaza-leftalone/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://jheberg.net/captcha/plaza-leftalone/&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;GO4UP&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://go4up.com/dl/12a9e74f7690/plaza-left.alone1.iso&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://go4up.com/dl/12a9e74f7690/plaza-left.alone1.iso&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;MULTI LINKS&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.multiup.org/download/e3e833e74d99bb97f9047796ad546da3/plaza-left.alone.iso&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; data-cke-saved-href=&quot;http://www.multiup.org/download/e3e833e74d99bb97f9047796ad546da3/plaza-left.alone.iso&quot;&gt;Left.Alone-PLAZA.iso&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;TORRENT&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;blockquote&gt;&lt;p&gt;Enjoy&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div id=&quot;tabs-21024-0-1&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;game_area_sys_req_leftCol&quot;&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;MINIMUM:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;ul&gt; &lt;li&gt; &lt;ul class=&quot;bb_ul&quot;&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;OS:&lt;/strong&gt; Windows 7 64-bit&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Processor:&lt;/strong&gt; Quad-core CPU ~ 2.5Ghz&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Memory:&lt;/strong&gt; 2 GB RAM&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Graphics:&lt;/strong&gt; GTX 560m / HD6870 1GB or equivalent&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DirectX:&lt;/strong&gt; Version 10&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Storage:&lt;/strong&gt; 1 GB available space&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div id=&quot;tabs-21024-0-3&quot;&gt;&lt;center&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;iframe src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/EPe5_1wp44Y&quot; width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen=&quot;allowfullscreen&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/center&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;div id=&quot;tabs-21024-0-4&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;codecolorer-container text twitlight&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;text codecolorer&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Left Alone Free Download&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt; 1. Extract release&lt;br /&gt; 2. Mount ISO&lt;br /&gt; 3. Install the game&lt;br /&gt; 4. Copy crack from the PLAZA folder&lt;br /&gt; 5. Play!&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt;  &lt;div style=&quot;font-size:0px;height:0px;line-height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;clear:both&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;wp_rp_wrap  wp_rp_vertical_m&quot; id=&quot;wp_rp_first&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;wp_rp_content&quot;&gt;&lt;h3 class=&quot;related_post_title&quot;&gt;You May Also Like:&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;ul class=&quot;related_post wp_rp&quot;&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;0&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-22746&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;1&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-22789&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;2&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-22385&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;3&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-1216&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;4&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-23032&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li data-position=&quot;5&quot; data-poid=&quot;in-23056&quot; data-post-type=&quot;none&quot; &gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;                                                         &lt;/div&gt;</content></entry></feed>
```

I get the error, When I use to get data from it using xmls function in php. I get correct result and when I try my blogger rss feed or some other website's feeds I get correct results,So my codes which use to get data from xml is correct but the above code may be wrong or I am doing some thing else.

Your approach will be highly appreciable for me. Please help me

Comment: I have given the output please see the post again

Comment: You'll need the default namespace xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' on the <feed> element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of htmlentities() function you can use the format of rss 2.0, I call it second way. Any ways, You can use.

```
<![CDATA[".$VARIABLE."]]>
```

Hope it works for you.